# How to connect to oci instance using DSN from MySQL Command line?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a dsn string:

> oci:dbname=(DESCRIPTION_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=off)(FAILOVER=on)
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=bob-1.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)
> (SERVICE_NAME=BBAPP.WORLD)))(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
> (HOST=bob-2.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=BBAPP.WORLD))))

I have the username and password commensurate with this same DB connection.

I want to connect to this database using the mysql command line utility.

Here is what I tried:

> mysql -u my_uname -p -P 1521 -h bob-1.com

It gave me a password prompt - I entered the password. Then it choked out on the premise that it could not identify a SQL instance on host bob-1.com. My thought is that I need to pass the entire DSN string, not just one of the two hosts mentioned. I don't know how to do that, though.

Is it possible to connect to a database using a dsn string like above using the mysql command line? If so - how do I achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to connect to an Oracle instance with the MySQL client program. That doesn't work. Use SQL*PLUS or another Oracle client.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use the MySQL command line utility rather than one of the Oracle command line utilities?

Answer (score 1):

The [mysql client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) is only a client for MySQL Server. It specifically uses the MySQL protocol, which is not supported by Oracle database. You cannot use a MySQL client to connect to Oracle, nor can you use that client to connect to Microsoft SQL Server, or PostgreSQL, or ODBC, etc. Each of these are different interfaces.

This has nothing to do with the DSN you use. It's the protocol that is incompatible.